# What is shourtcut for files in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I realy dont know how to ask this one, so I will try to describe it.
I am pretty sure that there is a shortcut in NetBeans for files. 
And when I want to get path to **web/img/sample/fileWithStrangeName** I dont want to type it and make some mistake.

What is shortcut in netbeans for that kind of navigation?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the http://wiki.netbeans.org/Keyboard_Shortcuts there is no direct way to do this using a keyboard shortcut for any version until now.

What i do is right clicking on a **file** and then select `properties`. And then copy the value of the `All Files` property.

Another way is to use the plugin `Explore from here`, that opens the file in its location. And then copy the path from that window.